# NextJS - custom Server Side Generation Key

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I have this ecommerce website in which urls are constructed like this:

[http://example.com/{slug}/{type}/{id}/{A}/{B}/{C}/{D}](http://example.com/%7Bslug%7D/%7Btype%7D/%7Bid%7D/%7BA%7D/%7BB%7D/%7BC%7D/%7BD%7D)

Parameters `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` are irrelevant to the response (you will get the same response regardless what values you pass; you can even pass nothing, just [http://example.com/{slug}/{type}/{id}](http://example.com/%7Bslug%7D/%7Btype%7D/%7Bid%7D)). In the same time it is a business requirement to have these parameters in url in this form (these are parsed from url and used on client side to do some stuff)

I'm using `getStaticProps` to get props on server, but due to the huge number of possible values of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` I cannot come with reasonable list of urls I could use in `getStaticPaths`. This means I cannot prerender these pages properly and I'm left with Server Side Rendering at request time, which affects performance.

What I'm looking for is a way to force NextJS to use the same cache key (?) so that both `/someSlug/T/123/irrelevant/parts/of/the/query` and `/someSlug/T/123/other/meaning/less/parameters` hit the same cache value stored as a result of `getStaticProps` for url of `/someSlug/T/123`

It seems it was raised as a [ticket](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/23648) but with no responses

Comment: can you conver the client side code to get the client side parameters from a hash?

`http://example.com/{slug}/{type}/{id}#{A}/{B}/{C}/{D}`

Comment: You can always pre-render a limited number of pages (with `getStaticPaths`) and  let the others being rendered on background once a user visits the pages, is this way  only one user will be affected by slowness while the others will visits the cached version of the page. or even better use on demand revalidation from the backend of your ecommerce